# How to get value from TexonomyField in Sequentail Workflow for Document Library?

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem

I am create Sequential Workflow for document library in Visual Studio 2010 and also create Meta Data Column Field which field name is TexonomyType.

first ways i get TexonomyField like this:

```
    TaxonomyField tf = (TaxonomyField)workflowProperties.Item["TexonomyType"];
```

tf is null

than try this ways :

```
        TaxonomyField tf = workflowProperties.Item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("TexonomyType") as TaxonomyField;

        TaxonomyFieldValue taxonomyFieldValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue(fieldToSet);

        string value = taxonomyFieldValue.Label;
```

here i got the TaxonomyField but Label getting always `Empty`.

How to Get TaxonomyField value for Current listitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code which use following classes to get the Taxonomy Field labels..

```
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection coll = (list.Items[0]["Field Name"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue val in coll)
        {
            // get termguid
            string termGuid = val.TermGuid;

            // get label
            string label = val.Label;

            // build the string
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("GUID: {0}, Label: {1}", termGuid, label));
        }

        lblFieldViewer.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I am using its only Taxonomyfield not TaxonomyMulti type. when i have try this code getting error like : cannt cast from `TaxonomyField` to `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection `

Comment: hope you are not casting workflowProperties.Item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("TexonomyType").. are you? which line is throwing error?

Comment: no its works.but when i go for get `TaxonomyFieldValue` with for label value always getting Empty.

Comment: Technet:Setting and Getting a Metadata field http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21801.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-c.aspx#Setting_and_Getting_a_Managed_Metadata_Field

Answer (score 0):

I found the value by below way:

```
        TaxonomyField fieldToSet = ListItem.Fields["TexonomyType"] as TaxonomyField;
        string value = string.Empty;
        if (fieldToSet != null)
        {
            object itemObj = ListItem["TexonomyType"];
            value = Convert.ToString(fieldToSet.GetFieldValueAsText(itemObj));
        }
```

Hops its helps.